# Play two nlatracks simultaneously

Tags: nla-editor

I run in to problem with nla editor, I cant play two tracks simultaneously if they start and end at same time, the track on top is only which is played, if I move only one to side I get transition from one to another but not both played simultaneously ? Any suggestion tnx